# How to check if user is on same view after resumes the activity from background to foreground in android

Tags: android

How to check if user is on same view after resumes the activity in android.

Regards,
AA.

Comment: Please clarify your problem?

Comment: We have one activity ,in which we have two buttons as share and document. If we clicked on document button another view gets opened in same activity.If application goes background and user is on same view i.e.(document),how to check if user is on same view?

Comment: use a boolean flag for state checking! when the view is opened set `isOpened = true` and when the view is closed set `isOpened = false`

Answer (score 0):

If my understanding is correct about your question,

The `onResume` override method will be called.

```
protected void onResume()
{
   super.onResume();
Log.d("MY_CLASS","User is here");
// User is still here.
}
```

if you want to check if the view is visible or not, You can do the following.

```
if(view.isVisible()
{

// Your code here.
}
```

Please Read the Activity LifeCycle  [HERE](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)

Comment: how we can check in onresume if the activity resumes again with same view in android?

Comment: Please check my updated answer. You can check whether the particular View is visible or not. `view.isVisible()`

Comment: can u please tell me how to get that view?

Comment: I am trying something below to get view                        RelativeLayout rootLinearLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.bottomLayout);
  int count = rootLinearLayout.getChildCount();
  for (int i = 0; i <= count; i++) {
   View v = rootLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
   if (!(v.isShown()) ){

Comment: `LinearLayout userLayout = (LinearLayout)findviewById(R.id.userLayout);`  You can check `userLayout`  is visible or not by the above piece of code.